Find all actual comments from GitHub user
I'm currently using the Search query of commenter:user-name but this seems to include any PR where the user has 1) Commented (yay) or 2) Just approved but no actual comment.
I wish to find all actual COMMENTS of a user.  Is there a way to filter down this list?
